# Why is state variable necessary for Facebook login

Tags: facebook, csrf

Facebook's server-side login process mentions that [the server should provide a 'state' variable during the request to Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/#step3). It acts like a CSRF token in which Facebook will pass back to login-callback page for our server to verify.

However I am not sure why this is necessary. If we do get a bogus login request, we still need to get the access_token from Facebook using the `?code=` of the login request. A bogus request will not have the correct `code`, therefore won't work correctly.

Furthermore, a user can access our server through ***Facebook App***'s link. Facebook automatically adds a `?code=` param to the link [so our server can/have-to auto login the user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/#websites). If we are to use `code` provided by this referral, we have no `state` param to verify anyways, and Facebook seems to not care about it either.

Is `state` optional? Does it really provide extra security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `state` parameter is optional. It may provide extra security if *your* service can put some information there worth keeping. Usually the `state` parameter is used for keeping data about the state of the session for the current browser window (as opposed to data dealing whole session which can be handled with cookies).

An example of using this feature for extra security would be doing following:

1. User visits your site
2. Your site sets session cookie (e.g. `Set-Cookie: id=xyzrandomstuff`)
3. User tries to do something that requires doing facebook authentication
4. Your site creates CSRF token that can be used with session id `xyzrandonstuff` and puts that in the `state` parameter for the facebook login
5. User completes login at facebook (you cannot see this)
6. User comes back from facebook with `code` and `state` parameters.
7. You verify login with `code` and before completing the action started at step 3 *your* server verifies that the CSRF token matches the current session.